# What are the minimal G Suite privileges needed to take over as Super Admin

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I am the Super Admin for my company's G Suite and would like to set up permissions for my CEO so that she can take over as (or reassign the) Super Admin should something happen to me. We would like to do this by giving her the *absolute minimum permissions necessary* to do so, so that until she takes that step, no other settings can be accidentally changed by her.

What are the minimal G Suite privileges that a user needs to have to be able to take over as Super Admin, or to assign Super Admin to another user?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a different tact with the same result:

Create a new super-admin account with a very strong password and secured with a UbiKey. Give the CEO the credentials and Ubikey and make it very clear it's for Break Glass situations, the kind of thing they should keep split between 2 safes.

This was you can keep the CEO's normal account at base-level permissions but they still have the ability to take over if something happens.

Answer (score 0):

The pre built Privileges are [Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986?hl=en&ref_topic=9832445).

As you can see only the Super admin can 'Create or assign administrator roles', check the paragraph ---> 'Only super administrators can..'

That being said you can personalise the privileges, check [This article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043?hl=en&ref_topic=9832445).

For a complete definition of the role check this [Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?hl=en).

Having said that I advice you the set the CEO as either 'User Management Admin', 'Help Desk Admin' or 'Services Admin'. At least in the begging stick to these pre built roles before start to personalise. This is because personalise the privileges is bit cumbersome if you are not familiar, furthermore you should first really understand what each privileges does.

---

> > EDIT  As reported in the Articles, in order to assign these Admin roles follow these steps:

1. Go to Admin.google.com as Super Admin.
2. Go to 'Users' and select the user you want to give privilege.
3. It will open a new window, at about the middle open 'Admin Roles and privileges'.
4. From this window you can then assign the wanted role and then save the changes.

---

### If you want to create a customer role go to admin.google.com and follow these steps:

1. Go to 'Admin roles'
2. From the top left corner choose 'Create New role'
3. Give a new for the new role and a description
4. In the new tab choose the Privilege name from the privilege hierarchy tree
5. Select 'continue' and then 'Create role'

---

Comment: That's what I'm seeking. Where do I assign just the privilege that would allow a user to make themselves a Super User?

Comment: I edited the answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Only a super admin can assign another user as super admin.

From [Make a user an admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176?hl=en)

> Make a user a super admin
> You're seeing steps for assigning admin roles to users at example.com.
>
> Here's how to grant a user full access to your Admin console:
>
> *You must be signed in as a super administrator for this task.*